# how to solve 404 post error in bot framework emulator as using hosted url on godadday?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, botframework, chatbot

I have created bot using echo bot template of visual studio and then hosted it on godadday, used that url to registered  on microsof bot framework, created app id and password which is given in visual studio code and on microsoft bot framework while registering it, When i going to test bot on emulator i used hosted url microsoft app id and microsoft password on bot emulator but it shows post 404 error, why does this appear? How can I solve it?

[image: Console error]

Comment: endpoint url :  https://echobot.masycoda.com/api/messages  MIcroosoft id:0da30554-fe46-462b-b31a-983a2878b532 ,, https://echobot.masycoda.com it is working fine,, but https://echobot.masycoda.com/api/messages gives not found

Comment: Have you checked if you need any dns entries on GoDaddy side to get things working?

Comment: Can you post the Configure method code of your Startup.cs file? I believe it should contain some configs to map the controller's endpoints

Comment: Is the bot .NET Core or .NET Framework? MVC/WebAPI? Are you basing this off of a [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-samples)? If you are getting a 404, then it is likely just due to routing inside your application.